Unable to connect to Cloudflare WARP
I'm on the latest macOS (15.2) and I can't figure out what's wrong with Cloudflare WARP. Every time I start it, it says "Registration in Progress" and then the following error
Status: Unable to Connect
Error reason: Registration Missing
Error code: CF_REGISTRATION_MISSING
Error description: Please connect to your Zero Trust organization and re-authenticate.
Learn more: https://cfl.re/CF_REGISTRATION_MISSING

I assuming it is trying to use ZeroTrust account (which I never had and the account tab in settings is blank and always loading, and it displays the contents of the tab only when there a disruption in the network connection or I try to re-connect warp). I need it to be set to personal use (not Zero Trust).


With that said, I use WARP on my android and it works fine, and both devices use the same network, so I'm not sure what's going on.
Any suggestions?
